# SHA1 hashing not working as expected in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a small Java code to see how to properly use SHA1.

Following is the code snippet I came up with:

```
package dummyJavaExp;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Exp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "Hello there";
        String hashstr = new String(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(str.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Encrypted value of " + str + " is: " + hashstr);
    }

}
```

But the above code gives some weird characters as shown in the following output message when I run the above code:

```
Encrypted value of Hello there is: rlvU>?Þ¢‘4ónjòêì\Î
```

I thought the encrypted message will be some alphanumeric string.

Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: encrypted message is array of bytes, maybe you want base64

Comment: ok, so how do I get alphanumeric string. I want to use the generated hashes as keys in a hashmap. I can't use bytes as keys.

Comment: It depends on your purpouses. If you need to encrypt a value, you must use MessageDigest; once you get the encrypted byte array you can think to create a base64 string. If you just need a base64 string, well you can directly create it from the original string

Comment: 1. Don't use String.getBytes(), which uses your platform default encoding. Use String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), which uses UTF_8 and is thus guaranteed to work the same way everywhere and support any character. 2. Encode the result using Base64 or Hex encoding.

Comment: Some puristic remark: the result is a hash value, not an encrypted value. The latter somehow suggests that you could decrypt it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for suggesting `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. I would have accepted your response as answer if it is an answer instead of comment. I do plan to run it on different systems so this charater set would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `String sample = new String(byte[] bytes)` it will create a string with platform's default charset, your digest bytes may not have alphanumeric representation in that charset.

Try to use Base64 or HexString to display digest message.

For example in JAVA8:

You can encode your digest bytes to string with:

```
String hashstr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

You can decode your Base64 with:

```
byte [] digest = Base64.getDecoder().decode(hashstr);
```